# using http request parameters in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am generating a table of data from a simple list of objects that I am displaying in a jsp page. Each row has a View hyper link attached to it. When the user clicks on the hyper link I need to send them to another controller (hooked up via a bean) to display more detailed information. I am trying to pass a unique id but in the controller that handles the request, when I try to retrieve the uniqueId via request.getParameter("uniqueId") it is always null.

So how should I handle requestParameter's in Spring MVC?

Update:

An example from my jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="file" items="${confirmationFiles}">
        <tr>
            <td>${file.batchId}</td>
            <td>${file.runDate}</td>
            <td>${file.customerId}</td>
            <td>${file.userName}</td>
            <td><a href="view-detail.do?batchId=${file.batchId}">View</a></td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

in my servlet configuration, I have:

```
<bean name="/view-detail.do"
    class="ViewDetailController">
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more Spring-specific ways to work with parameters, such as using the @RequestParam annotation, but if getParameter isn't working I wouldn't expect the annotation to work either; it sounds like the value isn't making it into the request.

How are you passing the ID when the user clicks the link?  Is it a querystring, or are you using javascript to make a POST request?  It would help if you gave us some sample code from your JSP.

Updated based on more info:  OK, so you're using a querystring.  When you click the link, can you see the correct ID in the URL?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not currently using annotations. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that your param is named `batchId` rather than `uniqueId`. So try that instead. If it is still null, try `request.gatParameterNames()` and list them all to see what has been submitted. Also, make sure your form enctype is not multipart.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistype on my part entering it in SO.